# Display website in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have the following method which will launch and load a page an HTML page in the default browser:

```
try {
            String url = "file:///C:/Users/Steve/Google%20Drive/Higher%20National%20Diploma%201/Semester%201/Assignments/Object%20Oriented%20Programming%20(Java)/Steve_Azzopardi_HND3/help/lotto.html";
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            desktop.browse(new URI(url));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Help file was not found");
        }
```

It works fine but I want to make it more versatile, meaning if I move the file it won't break the link. I have moved the file to the directory of the project so when I move the project the HTML page moves with it. How can I do such a thing?

EDIT :
updated code

```
try {
            String url = new File("help/lotto.html").getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(url);
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            desktop.browse(new URI(url));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Help file was not found");
        }
```

Url output : C:\Users\Steve\Google Drive\Higher National Diploma 1\Semester 1\Assignments\Object Oriented Programming (Java)\Steve_Azzopardi_HND3\help\lotto.html

Exception stack trace : java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\Steve

Comment: Put your resource in the classpath and load it from there.

Comment: What do you mean? sorry

Comment: [Start here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)).

Comment: @Colosuslol Do you want classpath or the answer I provided?

Comment: file:/ needs to be prepended to your string

Comment: @NoaNoNym Still gives me the same error

Comment: I tried something else which should give you the right uri...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in the classpath ( best solution in my opinion ). But you can also do this in java:

```
String currDir = new File("").getAbsolutePath(); //project directory
```

Put the file in a directory you would like to use, for example the project directory itself. Put the html file there, and if you move your project you move it too.

But I think you want to create a html folder inside the directory:

project_path/help/lotto.html

Then you can load it like this:

```
try {
       File f = new File("help/lotto.html");
       URI uri = f.toURI();
       Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
       desktop.browse(uri);
} catch (Exception ex) {
       System.out.println("Help file was not found");
}
```

Comment: tried you code it gives me error file cannot be stored in string,

Comment: Yep done it myself right now lol. The path is given properly but now uri doesn't work because of backslashes.

Comment: Do you perhaps have to add file:/// to the string? which string does url contain now

Comment: Added the new code in the question to give you a better explanation

Comment: This is wrong. `new File("")` gives the path to the CWD not the project directory, these will be different immediately the project is launched but double-clicking for example. And if the OP decides to package the project as a `jar` then this will be one of 10,000 questions asking why their resource access code no longer works. This isn't the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put your resource in the classpath so that your path address becomes the path of the file in your working directory. I think that should solve it completely.

Comment: Can you give an example please. not understanding

Comment: Copy your file to the folder wherein your generated app files are kept. Then, read it from there